# Индексы в SQL и производительность

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеем базу с 1 млн. строк. Как можно проверить - насколько индексы повышают производительность при выборке?

Comment: сравните выполнение запросов без индексов и с индексами

Answer (score 4):

Единственный реальный способ - сравнить на живых данных одну и ту же выборку - с индексами и без. При запуске вывести статистику по времени и IO:

```
set statistics time on
set statistics io on

select * from ....
```

Это даст вам вывод вида:

```
Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 9, logical reads 44240, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 250 ms,  elapsed time = 54 ms.
```

В ней стоит обратить внимание на CPU Time и на Logical Reads - именно они в первую очередь отражают общую производительность. Чем меньше - тем лучше.

Logical Reads отражает общее количество данных, к которым обратился ваш запрос.
CPU time отражает время, потраченное на их обработку (сотировки, джойны, прочие вычисления).

Обратите внимание, что вывод плана влияет на результаты измерения, так что убедитесь что опция Include Actual Execution Plan *выключена* перед замерами.

Кроме того, первое выполнение запроса может занять дольше, чем второе - из-за того, что промахи мимо кэша превращаются в Physical Reads. Поэтому стоит сравнивать на разогретом кэше - выполнять запрос несколько раз подряд, и отбрасывать первые измерения, или вообще отбрасывать измерения с ненулевым PR.

Comment: @Vega да, но в этом случае это скорее input